# Vertex Label in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn several graphs using tikz. Right now I am getting the vertex label inside the vertex. But  I want the labels of vertices outside it.

Also I want to draw two tickz pictures in one line. Please help.
I am using the following code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,circle,thick,draw}]
    \node(A) at (1,1) {1};
    \node(B) at (0,0) {2};
    \node(C) at (1,-1) {3};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
            [every edge/.style={draw=black,very thick}]
    \path[-](A)edge node {} (B);
    \path[-](B) edge node {} (C);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\medskip

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,circle,thick,draw}]
    \node(A) at (0,0) {2};
    \node(B) at (-1,1) {4};
    \node(C) at (1,1) {6};
    \node(D) at (1,-1) {8};
    \node(E) at (-1,-1) {10};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
            [every edge/.style={draw=black,very thick}]
    \path[-](A)edge node {} (B);
    \path[-](A) edge node {} (C);
    \path[-](A) edge node {} (D);
    \path[-](A) edge node {} (E);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Figure 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, based on assumption,that you wish two figures side by side and not subfigures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=black,very thick},
 vrtx/.style args = {#1/#2}{% 
      circle, draw, thick, fill=white,
      minimum size=5mm, label=#1:#2}
                    ]
\node(A) [vrtx=left/1] at (1, 1) {};
\node(B) [vrtx=left/2] at (0, 0) {};
\node(C) [vrtx=left/3] at (1,-1) {};
%
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (B) edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption*{Figure 1}  
    &   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=black,very thick},
 vrtx/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
      circle, draw, thick, fill=white,
      minimum size=5mm, label=#1:#2}
                    ]
\node (A) [vrtx=left/2]     at ( 0, 0) {};
\node (B) [vrtx=left/4]     at (-1, 1) {};
\node (C) [vrtx=right/6]    at ( 1, 1) {};
\node (D) [vrtx=right/8]    at ( 1,-1) {};
\node (E) [vrtx=left/10]    at (-1,-1) {};
 %
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (A) edge (C)
        (A) edge (D)
        (A) edge (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Figure 2}  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

I also slightly change code to make it more concise and easy to use (omit are `scope`s, defined node for simple settings their labels, omitted are not used nodes ad edges. Figures are placed in `tabularx` table.

**Addendum:**
In case, that you like to organize figures in one line as sub figures:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=black,very thick},
 vrtx/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
      circle, draw, thick, fill=white,
      minimum size=5mm, label=#1:#2}
                    ]
\node(A) [vrtx=left/1] at (1, 1) {};
\node(B) [vrtx=left/2] at (0, 0) {};
\node(C) [vrtx=left/3] at (1,-1) {};
%
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (B) edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=black,very thick},
 vrtx/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
      circle, draw, thick, fill=white,
      minimum size=5mm, label=#1:#2}
                    ]
\node (A) [vrtx=left/2]     at ( 0, 0) {};
\node (B) [vrtx=left/4]     at (-1, 1) {};
\node (C) [vrtx=right/6]    at ( 1, 1) {};
\node (D) [vrtx=right/8]    at ( 1,-1) {};
\node (E) [vrtx=left/10]    at (-1,-1) {};
 %
\path   (A) edge (B)
        (A) edge (C)
        (A) edge (D)
        (A) edge (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Common caption}
    \label{fig:figure-3}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In above MWE is used environments `subfigure` from package `subcaption`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % lualatex engine
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
     \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style = {draw,very thick},
                    vertex/.style args = {#1 #2}{circle, 
                                                draw, thick,
                                                minimum size=5mm, 
                                                label=#1:#2}]
\path node(A) [vertex=left 1] at (1, 1) {} 
      node(B) [vertex=left 2] at (0, 0) {} 
      node(C) [vertex=left 3] at (1,-1) {} 
      (A) edge (B)                         
      (B) edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{graph}
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style = {draw,very thick},
                    vertex/.style args = {#1 #2}{circle, 
                                                 draw, 
                                                 thick,
                                                 minimum size=5mm, 
                                                 label=#1:#2}]
\path   node (A) [vertex=left 2]     at ( 0, 0) {} 
        node (B) [vertex=left 4]     at (-1, 1) {} 
        node (C) [vertex=right 6]    at ( 1, 1) {} 
        node (D) [vertex=right 8]    at ( 1,-1) {} 
        node (E) [vertex =left 10]   at (-1,-1) {}
       (A) edge (B)
       (A) edge (C)
       (A) edge (D)
       (A) edge (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{graph bis}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]